# When to use transient, when not to in flink?

Tags: apache-flink

in this code, should i use `transient`?

when can i use `transient`?

what is the difference ?

need your help

```
private              Map<String, HermesCustomConsumer> topicSourceMap                 = new ConcurrentHashMap();
private              Map<TopicAndPartition, Long>      currentOffsets                 = new HashMap<>();
private transient Map<TopicAndPartition, Long>         restoredState;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**
If you use `transient` variable, you'd better instantiate it in `open()` method of operators which implemented `Rich` interface. Otherwise, declare the variable with an initial value at the same time.

The states you use here are called raw states managed by the user itself. Whether you should use `transient` modifier depending on serialization purpose. Before you submit the Flink job. The computation topology will be generated and distributed into Flink cluster. And operators including source and sink will instantiate with fields e.g, `topicSourceMap` in your code. Variables `topicSourceMap` and `currentOffsets` have been instantiated with constructor. While `restoredState` is a transient variable, thus no matter what initial value you assigned with, it will not be serialized and distributed into some task to execute. So you usually need to instanciate it in `open()` method of operator which implemented `Rich` interface. After this operator is deserialized in some task, `open()` method would be invoked into instantiate your own states.

Comment: if you're using scala, an alternative to initializing your transient variables in the `open()` hook is to make them lazy, so that they're initialized on first access.  e.g. `@transient lazy val topicSourceMap = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, HermesCustomConsumer]()`

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the only thing that distinguishes normal variables from transient is what they get initialized with on the cluster during execution. Transient vars get initialized with a default value for their datatype. @mziwisky if you are initializing yours with an empty `ConcurrentHashMap` anyway, why do you make it `transient`?

Comment: it's been 2 years since i've touched flink and scala, so i have no idea ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯